# Comfy CMS site not found

Tags: content-management-system, comfortable-mexican-sofa

Suddenly I'm getting:
ActionController::RoutingError 
Site Not Found.
and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? 
I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2 and Comfortable Mexican Sofa cms.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in this question for some-one who has no idea what your implementation is like to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `Cms::Site` created yet. Or hostname/path doesn't match to whatever you have. Get into admin area (`/cms-admin` most likely) and see what you have in Sites section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured this out by now, but I was just demoing sofa and I found that even though the instructions say to go to 127.0.0.1:3000/cms-admin

The actual default installation is actually /admin - not /cms-admin

So with rails 4, ruby 2 and a default install if you follow the github get started docs you will get a routing error until you go to /admin...

Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've already run

> ```
> bundle install (with gem comfortable_mexican_sofa inside)
>
> rails generate comfy:cms
>
> rake db:migrate
> ```

After that, just access `http://localhost:3000/admin` and type this default account: 
**username**/**password**

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your server.

Go to Terminal

navigate to folder

enter *rails s*

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the port number in the "Hostname" field of a site if your server is not running on a standard port (e.g. localhost:3000). If you forget the port it may run with one site. After creating a second site I couldn't invoke any sites with missing ports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this here, even though the question isn't great: When you configure the sites, it must not start with a forward slash. This only affects you if you've configured multiple sites, but when trying to find the correct site it will prepend a forward slash.

so, in Edit Site:

```
Path  my/path
```

NOT

```
Path /my/path
```